# use async-await with subscription

Tags: node.js, angular

I would like to fix this `callback hell` I have written, using async-await. can anyone please explain how can I use async-await so that code is a bit less horrible to debug.

```
              this.ws.call('vm.image_path', ['RancherOS']).subscribe((img_path)=>{
            if(!img_path){
              this.dialog.Info('CHECKSUM MISMATCH', 'system checks failed to verify ISO, please try rebooting Virtual Machine');
              this.loader.close();
              return;
            };
            this.ws.call('vm.decompress_gzip',[img_path, this.raw_file_path]).subscribe((decompress_gzip)=>{
              this.ws.call('vm.raw_resize',[this.raw_file_path, this.raw_file_path_size]).subscribe((raw_resize)=>{
                this.ws.call('vm.start',[this.cards[index].id]).subscribe((vm_start)=>{
                    this.loader.close();
                    if(!vm_start){
                      this.dialog.Info('ERROR', 'vm failed to start, please check system log.');
                      return;
                    }
                    this.refreshVM(index, this.cards[index].id);

                  });
                },
                (error_raw_resize)=>{
                  this.loader.close();
                  new EntityUtils().handleError(this, error_raw_resize);
                })
            },(decompress_gzip)=>{
              this.loader.close();
              new EntityUtils().handleError(this, decompress_gzip);
          });
          },(error_img_path)=>{
            this.loader.close();
            new EntityUtils().handleError(this, error_img_path);
          });
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `ws.call()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use RxJs [`toPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) operator to make life simpler

**SomeService**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

// ..

public async someFunction() {
    let response = await this._http.get<any>(this.apiURL).toPromise();
    return response;
}
```

To call the method,

```
public async getProducts() {
    try {
        let response = await this.someService.someFunction();
        // do something with response
    } 
    catch (e) {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

IMO writing async methods this way is much cleaner and debuggable.